# OpenGL pausing problems

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have the following function that is used as the `glutKeyboardFunc` function parameter:

```
void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, //The key that was pressed
                    int x, int y) {    //The current mouse coordinates
    switch (key) {
        case 27: //Escape key
            exit(0); //Exit the program
    }

    if (key == 'a')
    {
        moveCircleLeft(0);
    }
    if (key == 'w')
    {
        moveCircleUp(0);
    }
    if (key == 's')
    {
        moveCircleDown(0);
    }
    if (key == 'd')
    {
        moveCircleRight(0);
    }
}
```

Now I will show you `moveCircleLeft` as an example of how the `moveCircle` functions are written:

```
void moveCircleLeft(int x)
{
    characterX = characterX - 0.1;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    x++;
    if (x < 10)
    {
        glutTimerFunc(10, moveCircleLeft, x);
    }
}
```

The other `moveCircle` functions work similar and the only differences between the four functions is whether its plus of minus 0.1 or if it is `characterY` as opposed to `characterX`.

Now, here is the problem:

All the directions are moving in the right direction but, there is a delay/pause in movement of the character when I try to press keys. So, if I press just the d key (moveCircleRight) it moves right a little, stops a for a small amount of time, then moves across the screen in that direction at a constant speed with no pauses. Then if I change to a different key it pause for a little bit before changing directions then moves at a constant speed in that direction.

Any suggestion around this would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using a switch for a single condition, and then using separate if statements for all the others?

Comment: I did have multiple arguments for the if statements and then got rid of them. Then I didn't really bother in changing it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `boolean` variable for each key (preferably an array). Then use `KeyDown/KeyUp` instead of `KeyPress` (i believe in GLUT its something like `KeyboardUpFunc` and `KeyboardFunc`, but cant remember now). On `KeyDown`, set the appropriate variable to true, on `KeyUp`, set it to false. Now you probably have an `Idle` function or something like that. Call there your "move" functions based on the boolean variables. There should be no pauses now. Beware though that you might need to keep track of the time elapsed between frames and scale the distance moved appropriately.

Comment: For me personally, I just set some kind of `dt` variable to `1 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND` (and obviously `#define FRAMES_PER_SECOND` somewhere).